# sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 65534, should be 0\nsudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-tower

I have the latest Ansible Tower configured on a RHEL 8.9

When I run specific ansible tasks, I always get this error message:

```json
{
    "module_stdout": "",
    "module_stderr": "sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 65534, should be 0\nsudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

Example of tasks would be:

```yml
    - name: Install cx_Oracle Python module
      pip:
        name: cx_Oracle
        state: present
    - name: Execute SQL to get Schemas from DB
      ibre5041.ansible_oracle_modules.oracle_sql:
        username: "{{ db_username }}"
        password: "{{ db_password }}"
        mode: "{{ 'sysdba' if ar_orcl_db_sql_user|upper == 'SYS' else 'normal' }}"
        hostname: "{{ db_host }}"
        service_name: "{{ db_service_name }}"
        port: "{{ db_port }}"
        #sql: "SELECT username FROM dba_users"
        sql: "SELECT NAME FROM v$database"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      register: schema_result
```

Note that, when I comment either one of the tasks, it always triggers the error.

I've confirmed that both file's owner is root, and I believe the setuid has been set.

Here's the proof:

```bash
$ ls -la /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x. 1 root root 165528 Dec  7  2021 /usr/bin/sudo

$ stat /usr/bin/sudo
  File: /usr/bin/sudo
  Size: 165528      Blocks: 328        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca02h/51714d    Inode: 9184962     Links: 1
Access: (4111/---s--x--x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:sudo_exec_t:s0
Access: 2024-02-23 12:17:03.876558806 +0000
Modify: 2021-12-07 12:02:43.000000000 +0000
Change: 2022-11-21 19:52:23.879128352 +0000
 Birth: 2022-11-21 19:47:26.179931860 +0000

$ stat /etc/sudo.conf
  File: /etc/sudo.conf
  Size: 1786        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca02h/51714d    Inode: 8619263     Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
Access: 2024-02-23 12:17:03.883558691 +0000
Modify: 2021-12-07 11:57:12.000000000 +0000
Change: 2022-11-21 19:52:23.873128307 +0000
 Birth: 2022-11-21 19:47:26.165931757 +0000
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: I know of two cases where the nobody user appears: 1/ NFS (eg: when the default `root_squash` is in effect on a \*nix server, and *maybe* also when NFSv4 doesn't have UID/GID extensions and can't map the (root) user) 2/ Linux user namespaces: when actual root is not mapped, it appears as the overflow uid which is nobody by default. Containers use user namespaces. systemd might too. Are some parts of your overall setup related to one of these two cases?

Comment: I would check what the `stat` module returns for `/etc/sudo.conf` with `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @A.B, from what I can understand `root_squash` is used on an NFS server, CMIIW. FYI, I don't use an NFS server here. I directly installed the Ansible Tower on a server. I assume the `NFSv4` thing is related to the NFS server as well, CMIIW. And, the server does not use containers, I've confirmed this by running `docker ps` and it triggered the `docker command not found` error.

However, I see that RHEL 8 uses `systemd`.

Comment: @AlexD, how do I check that? Is it possible to run it from the terminal? If it is, could you please give me a command example? I've tried the awx cli, I couldn't find any clue, but probably I'm missing something here.

Comment: Never mind my mention of systemd before, I actually don't see how it could matter. So I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for helping @A.B, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a complete answer on an ansible forum. I'm posting here the answer so that anyone who struggles with this issue will understand why this happens and how to solve it.

Basically, the old Tower 3.8 also has a mechanism to isolate the job execution process in another form (Bubblewrap) that is not Podman. You can find more information [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/proot_func_variables.html).

I've resolved the issue by adding `extra_args: "--user"` to the first task, and `become: false` to the second task.

For more details, you can check my post on another forum [here](https://forum.ansible.com/t/sudo-etc-sudo-conf-is-owned-by-uid-65534-should-be-0-nsudo-usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set/4035/10?u=budiantoip).

Comment: So in the end it is user namespaces as I commented before. example: https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap/issues/448 where the error is about the user namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Try ”become: false”, idk why it’s work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've posted this to an ansible forum, and got a complete explanation on what's going on. You can check it out [here](https://forum.ansible.com/t/sudo-etc-sudo-conf-is-owned-by-uid-65534-should-be-0-nsudo-usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set/4035/11?u=budiantoip)